# Are there official roadmaps or release dates for future Bluetooth versions?

Tags: bluetooth

I am currently researching about certain Bluetooth versions. 5.0 and 5.1 were released in 2016 and 2019, but I haven't been able to find a official statement of the SIG about the release of planned future versions (i.e. 5.2).

Are there any official roadmaps or release dates by the SIG?

Comment: There is a page called 'specifications in development' on their main website, however you'll have to log in to see what it has to offer :) (bluetooth.com -> specification -> specification in development)

Comment: Thank you FMashiro. Unfortunately it seems like the SIG memberships are only available for companies and business purposes.